# mod-rewrite htaccess folder rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Would it be possible so that http://mydomain.com/folder/index1.php could be rewritten so that anyone navigating to http://mydomain.com/folder/index1 would see index1.php if that makes sense?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way of setting this just to the specific file rather than having it site wide?

Comment: yes, see the last line. thats a regular expression: (.*) means match all characters. So just write a valid regex there that matches the  file name.